# Adding a file to docker image results in "permission denied" error

Tags: docker

I am creating a docker golang image, but my golang app needs to read a config.yaml on start. I tried to add the file as shown in the dockerfile below:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
# Install git + SSL ca certificates
RUN apk update && apk add git && apk add ca-certificates
# Create appuser
COPY . $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/app/
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/app/
#get dependancies
RUN go get -d -v
#build the binary
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /go/bin/app
# STEP 2 build a small image
# start from scratch
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
ADD ./config.yaml /go/bin/app/
# Copy our static executable
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /go/bin/app
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/app"]
```

But I get the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/go/bin/app\": permission denied": unknown.

Comment: The error pretty much explains the problem: It cannot execute `/go/bin/app` because permission is denied. Most likely, the execute bit isn't set.

Comment: `/go/bin/app` is a directory.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, the executable does not seem to have the executable bit set.

Since the `scratch` image does not include even the shell, you cannot change the file permissions in that block. But you can do it in the block before the scratch:

```
...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /go/bin/app
RUN chmod +x /go/bin/app
# STEP 2 build a small image
...
```

Comment: First thanks for the help, but
I am still getting an error, also when I run with sudo docker run ....  :`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/go/bin/app\": permission denied": unknown.`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the permission of execution of `app`, try to `chmod +x` to /go/bin/app after copying.

```
RUN chmod a+x /go/bin/app
```

Comment: I get the following error `OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown`

Comment: @user1990524 Please make a habit of reading your error messages thoroughly for understanding. That new error message, same as the original, tells you the problem:  /bin/sh does not exist.

Comment: @user1990524 If you are starting from scratch, sh doesn't exist.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I edited my code as suggested, and it still does not work. Thats we I posted the error. I feel like it should not to be so hard to make it possible for viper to read a config file from the current directory ....

Comment: @user1990524 What is viper ? What are you trying to do ??

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to run the below command, after copying the files

```
RUN chmod 700 /go/bin/app
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but turns out the problem was that I was trying to run my main function in a non main package. I was a very weird error for this problem, but running it locally first gave me the answer

Comment: +1 This fixed my problem. The main function was in a non-main package, because my IDE automatically generated the package name based on the folder i.e. `cmd/web` was `package web`.

Answer (score 0):

For persons seeing similar error while trying to execute a shell script, there is a suggestion on this [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29922#issuecomment-371589632). You could check if it'll work for you