# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345

Tags: docker, go, github, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions

Currently we are migrating from GitLab to GitHub and we've decided to move the CI/CD process to GitHub actions. The pipeline process works like a charm but when GKE tries to spin up the newly pushed image it gives back this error:

`'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/socket-server\": permission denied": unknown'`

It's important to note here that this whole process was working on GitLab. Anyway, the GitHub workflow yaml file looks like this:

```
name: Build and deploy
on:
  - push
  - pull_request

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: fusion-engineering/setup-git-credentials@v2
        with:
          credentials: https://${{ secrets.MACHINE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/

      - name: Setup environment
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "::set-env name=GOPATH::${{ github.workspace }}/go"
          echo "::add-path::${{ github.workspace }}/go/bin"

      - name: Install Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v1
        with:
          go-version: 1.12.4

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: go/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}

      - name: Prepare environment
        run: |
          cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          make prepare

      - name: Format code
        run: |
          cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          make fmt && git diff --exit-code

      - name: Lint code
        run: |
          cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          make lint

      - name: Vet code
        run: |
          cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          make vet

      - name: Test code
        run: |
          cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          make cover

      - name: Build code
        run: |
          cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          make build

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: socket-server
          path: go/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}/socket-server

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    if: contains(github.ref, 'refs/tags')

    steps:
      - name: Set release version
        run: echo ::set-env name=CI_COMMIT_TAG::${GITHUB_REF/refs\/tags\//}

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get artifact from build step
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: socket-server

      - name: Set ci auth
        run: echo ::set-env name=CI_AUTH::$(cat ci_auth.json | base64)

      - uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          service_account_key: ${{ env.CI_AUTH }}

      - name: Configure gcloud docker authentication
        run: |
          gcloud config set project foo
          gcloud auth configure-docker

      - name: Build, push and deploy container
        run: |
          bash deploy.sh
```

The deploy.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" ]]; then
    echo "CI_COMMIT_TAG is empty, this stage should not run"
    exit 0
fi

export ENV="stage"

if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" != "${CI_COMMIT_TAG%-release}" ]]; then
    export ENV="prod"
fi

echo "Current environment: $ENV"

make deploy
```

The deploy step in the Makefile looks like this:

```
deploy:
    ( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat k8s.yml.template; ) | sh > k8s-${ENV}.yml
    docker build --no-cache \
    --build-arg RELEASE=${CI_COMMIT_TAG} \
    --build-arg ENV=${ENV} \
    -t gcr.io/foo/socket-server:${CI_COMMIT_TAG} .
    docker push gcr.io/foo/socket-server:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
    gcloud container clusters get-credentials api-${ENV} --zone=europe-west1-b
    kubectl apply -f k8s-${ENV}.yml
```

And the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest as certs
RUN apk --update add ca-certificates

FROM scratch
COPY --from=certs /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

ARG RELEASE
ARG ENV

ADD ./socket-server /socket-server
ADD ./config.yml /config.yml
ADD ./dbconfig.yml /dbconfig.yml
ADD ./migrations /migrations

ENV SOCKET_SERVER_SENTRY_DSN https://foo@sentry.io/bar
ENV SOCKET_SERVER_SENTRY_RELEASE $RELEASE
ENV SOCKET_SERVER_SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT $ENV

CMD ["/socket-server", "--port", "9345", "--host", ""]
```

I have already tried to `chmod +x socket-server` on the pipeline and also in the Dockerfile ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460628/adding-a-file-to-docker-image-results-in-permission-denied-error)). When I do it in the Dockerfile it fails with the following error:

```
Step 14/15 : RUN chmod +x socket-server
 ---> Running in 9c66aef0c35b
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Am I missing something on the GitHub workflow or is there anybody who is seeing something that I don't? Some help is appreciated!

Comment: You won't have chmod in a scratch image, that's an empty base. You'd need to run chmod on the file before the build server before running docker build, or copy the file into another base image that includes chmod to fix it there.

Comment: @BMitch I have already tried running `chmod +x socket-server` on the pipeline before running the docker build (as stated in my question). But unfortunately that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found out that the uploaded artifact is put in a folder by the pipeline. So the `socket-server` was a directory and not the expected executable file. I fixed it by changing this:

```
- name: Get artifact from build step
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: socket-server
```

to

```
- name: Get artifact from build step
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: socket-server
          path: .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a chmod in another stage that includes the chmod binary and then copy the file with the corrected permissions into your final scratch based stage:

```
FROM alpine:latest as certs
RUN apk --update add ca-certificates

FROM alpine:latest as binaries
COPY ./socket-server /socket-server
RUN chmod 755 /socket-server

FROM scratch
COPY --from=certs /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

COPY --from=binaries /socket-server /
COPY ./config.yml /config.yml
COPY ./dbconfig.yml /dbconfig.yml
COPY ./migrations /migrations

ARG RELEASE
ARG ENV

ENV SOCKET_SERVER_SENTRY_DSN https://foo@sentry.io/bar
ENV SOCKET_SERVER_SENTRY_RELEASE $RELEASE
ENV SOCKET_SERVER_SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT $ENV

CMD ["/socket-server", "--port", "9345", "--host", ""]
```

Note that I've also switched from ADD to COPY since you don't want to unzip the binaries/yml files or pull them from a remote http server. And I've also moved the ARG entries down to where you use them to avoid breaking the cache prematurely (not an issue here, but would be with a RUN command).

Comment: First of all thanks for answering! I've tried this Dockerfile but I still get the error: `'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container
          process caused "exec: \"/socket-server\": permission denied": unknown'`. I was also thinking that maybe the `socket-server` executable wasn't present so I put an `ls` in the pipeline just before starting the deploy.sh script but the file is there..

Comment: @Sefa what's your host, Oracle Linux, RHEL? SELinux enabled?

Comment: The containers are hosted at the Google Cloud Platform using the Google Kubernetes Engine. The pipeline pushes them to the docker registry and kubernetes tries to start a new pod with the newly pushed version and there I can see that the pod cannot start and returns with the previously stated error.